# Circular depenncy issue while start the srping boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, circular-dependency

I added the Java melody configuration in my spring boot application after I start the embedded tomcat server, I'm getting the following error:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> Description:
>
> There is a circular dependency between 5 beans in the application
>   context:
>
> - activeOrderController (field private om.gov.moh.nehr.service.ActiveOrderService
>     om.gov.moh.nehr.controller.ActiveOrderController.activeOrderService)
> - activeOrderServiceImpl (field public om.gov.moh.nehr.data.repository.ActiveDiagnosticOrderRepo
>     om.gov.moh.nehr.service.impl.ActiveOrderServiceImpl.activeDiagnosticOrderRepo)
> - activeDiagnosticOrderRepo
> - (inner bean)#26d445e9
> - entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource [om/gov/moh/nehr/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]
> - dataSource

Comment: Error is self-explanatory. Review carefully your Spring beans. If you won't be able to find a circular dependency, consider posting mentioned 5 beans code here.

Comment: check the dependencies in these classes.

Comment: after adding the below class i got above error, otherwise its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to `@Autowire` beans in a class where they are instantiated. Can you double check that if you have defied these as `@Bean`? The spring container cannot inject them in the autowired fields since they are created in the same class.

Remove the `@Autowired` fields and try using directly to start with.